# Unity building for apple Tv with firebase

Tags: android, ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, tvos

I am trying to make a game with Unity for my appleTv. I am using Firebase as database. The game works fine and I can build the game on my phone, but when I wan't to build the game for my appleTv I get an error. The building also stops

This is the error:
Generation of the Firebase Android resource file google-services.xml from Assets/google-services.json failed.
If you have not included a valid Firebase Android resources in your app it will fail to initialize.

I don't know why an appleTv project complains for an Android rescource file and why the build stops every time. 
Anny help?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase SDKs for Unity are currently only supported on Android and iOS devices.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup

Comment: No, tvOS is not supported.

Comment: can I use the rest api in thOS?

Comment: You can use the rest API anywhere you can make an http connection.